# Calculating the prime factors of a number

Tags: c++, optimization, prime-factoring

I have the following request:

> find the PRIME factors (without their exponents) for a given number `n` with `2 < n < 999999`.

I have [the following algorithm](http://ideone.com/hlHt3Y) that solves the problem, but seems to have some performance issues:

```
bool is_prime(const unsigned long int &number) {
    for (unsigned long int i = 2; i <= sqrt(number); i++) {
        if (number%i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
unsigned long int next_prime(unsigned long int current) {
    current++;
    while (!is_prime(current)) {
        current++;
    }
    return current;
}

// THE PROBLEM SOLVER
vector<unsigned long int> find_divisors(const unsigned long int &n) {
    vector<unsigned long int> divisors;
    for (unsigned long int i = 2; i <= n; i = next_prime(i)) {
        if (n%i == 0) divisors.push_back(i);
    }
    return divisors;
}
```

**Issue:** for big numbers, the algorithm takes too much time (for the maximum allowed number, it takes about **1.5 seconds**).

**Examples (that are correct):**

- `n = 1620` outputs `{2, 3, 5}`
- `n = 2048` outputs `{2}`
- `n = 4096` outputs `{2}`

Comment: If a number `a` divides another number `b` evenly, `a` must be half of `b` or less. Fix your `for` loop and you should do many less computations.

Comment: Use a Sieve of Eratosthenes to pre-calculate all the primes from 2 up to the square root of the integer in question.  Save all the primes in a set and then your `is_prime` function just becomes a look up in the set.

Additionally, when making your sieve, make your condition `i * i < number` as it's faster than running a square root function.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh, do you refer to the loop in `p1()`?

Comment: Read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization and find which algorythm is suitable for your needs

Comment: @Victor Yes, I believe I do.

Comment: @Coda17 if he would have list of prime numbers then lookup is not necessary, he should just iterate on that container.

Comment: @Victor _"It might be too particular, but instead of downvoting, please, help me re-writing this for others to use."_ I didn't downvote (yet), but you'll need to make your question more _canonical_ for this purpose. 1st of all: Get rid of the non standard c++ `_tmain()` and `_getch()`, then.

Comment: Not a performance issue, but why the strange mix of types.  If `next_prime` and `is_prime` take an `int`, there's no point in using any other type anywhere.

Comment: I mistyped the code here. In my code I use `unsigned long int` everywhere,

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ, is it better now?

Comment: @Victor _"is it better now?"_ Not regarding the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) requirement. When I said get rid of `_tmain()`, I actually meant: Change your sample entry point to `int main(int argc, char* argv[]) { /* ... */ }`. Best would be, you work out a reproducible sample and behavior with a decent online IDE as e.g. [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/), or [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/), and link to it if you want to omit minor relevant code in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposed algorithm is, as you imply, horribly inefficient. But for the stated range, this is a very simple problem for computers with 32-bit integer arithmetic. This is how to do it:

```
for (int p = 2 ; p * p <= n ; p = (p == 2) ? 3 : (p + 2)) { // p = 2,3,5,7,9,...until p > sqrt(n)
  if (n % p) continue ;
  divisors.push_back (p) ;       // p divides n, so save it
  do n /= p ; while (!(n % p)) ; // Remove all divisors p from n
}
if (n > 1) divisors.push_back (n) ;
```

I am not going to explain this: you will learn much more by figuring it out for yourself. It could be made a little faster by various micro-optimisations, but it is essentially optimal for your stated range, unless you use prime tables. Such tables might make it a little faster, but in most cases it won't be worth it.

Comment: Yes, this is essentially the same as my answer. Mine avoids the branch at each increment (although this should be predicted, so not really a big deal).

Comment: @Charles: I agree -- this is the first micro-optimisation that I would make.

Comment: The next (for both of us) would be to compute a square root rather than multiplying each time; at the cost of O(log n) square roots we can save ~max(p, sqrt(q)) multiplications where p <= q are the largest two prime factors.

Comment: @Victor: You are absolutely correct! I have corrected the code (I hope).

Comment: Surely you want `(n > 1)`, not `(n)`?

Comment: well, since this is the most robust (for the file size) and seems to be a very fast algorithm (from my tests - it only took 3 milliseconds for `n=999999`), I will accept your answer!

Comment: @Victor for a worst case test you should use the largest prime less than 999999, which is 999983.

Comment: By using a table instead of trying all odd divisors, you reduce from 500 to 169 the number of divisibility tests in the worst case.

Answer (score 1):

The main optimization: you don't need to search up to n, you can just search to sqrt(n). Anything remaining is prime. Secondary optimization: divide out primes you find to reduce the bound to which you search.

More could be done but this is about a thousand times faster already.

```
vector<unsigned long int> find_divisors(const unsigned long int &m) {
  unsigned long int n = m;
  vector<unsigned long int> divisors;
  if (n%2 == 0) {
    divisors.push_back(2);
    while (n%2==0) n/=2;
  }

  for (unsigned long int i = 3; i*i <= n; i += 2) {
      if (n%i) continue;
      divisors.push_back(i);
      while (n%i==0) n/=i;
  }
  if (n > 1) divisors.push_back(n);
  return divisors;
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but for `n=10` (for example), it outputs `{2}`, instead of `{2,5}` because `sqrt(10) < 5`

Comment: @Victor: 5 is added by the line `if (n > 1) divisors.push_back(n);`.

Comment: I don't get the idea. `n` is always greater than 2, by the condition of the problem

Comment: In C/C++, the statement which causes a loop to advance without executing the rest of the block is `continue`, not `next`. (Also, I don't understand the signature of your function. What was wrong with `find_divisors(unsigned long n)`?)

Comment: @rici: Thanks for the fix. As for the signature, I copied it from Victor's original problem -- I wasn't sure if it was required for some reason. I would certainly prefer to do it that way.

Comment: @Victor: There are two lines which can modify n, so by the time that line is executed n may and may not be 1.

Comment: I am currently testing it. It seems to be the most promising

Comment: @Victor: I could make it faster but this is fast enough for most purposes.

Answer (score 1):

For such a limited range of numbers, it is quite acceptable to hard code a table of primes up to 1000.

```
int P[169]= {
    2,   3,   5,   7,  11,  13,  17,  19,  23,  29,  31,  37,  41,
   43,  47,  53,  59,  61,  67,  71,  73,  79,  83,  89,  97, 101,
  103, 107, 109, 113, 127, 131, 137, 139, 149, 151, 157, 163, 167,
  173, 179, 181, 191, 193, 197, 199, 211, 223, 227, 229, 233, 239,
  241, 251, 257, 263, 269, 271, 277, 281, 283, 293, 307, 311, 313,
  317, 331, 337, 347, 349, 353, 359, 367, 373, 379, 383, 389, 397,
  401, 409, 419, 421, 431, 433, 439, 443, 449, 457, 461, 463, 467,
  479, 487, 491, 499, 503, 509, 521, 523, 541, 547, 557, 563, 569,
  571, 577, 587, 593, 599, 601, 607, 613, 617, 619, 631, 641, 643,
  647, 653, 659, 661, 673, 677, 683, 691, 701, 709, 719, 727, 733,
  739, 743, 751, 757, 761, 769, 773, 787, 797, 809, 811, 821, 823,
  827, 829, 839, 853, 857, 859, 863, 877, 881, 883, 887, 907, 911,
  919, 929, 937, 941, 947, 953, 967, 971, 977, 983, 991, 997, 1009          
};

int i= 0;
while (i < 169 && P[i] < Number)
{
    if (Number % P[i] != 0)
        i++;
    else
        Number/= P[i]; // P[i] is a factor
}
// Number is the last factor
```

Comment: what if `n=29023*3*11` (which is `957759`)?

Comment: Successfully factored as 3.11.29023. This code works to 999999.

Comment: Indeed, this should work to 1026168.

Comment: @Charles 2.2.2.3.11.13.13.23; yep, fails on 1026169 = 1013.1013 (declared prime).

Answer (score 0):

You don't cache any of your results:
instead you should consider using

```
map<int,vector<int>> vPrimes
```

This map would contain all the prime factors of a given number.
For example for 50 it would contain 2,5 (2*5*5=50).
Then assume you try to compute it for 300 then you test (300%3=0) then you add 3 to the list, resulting in (2,3,5).

Hope that helps,

Comment: If you read my examples, I do not need the exponents for the factors, I only need the factors.

Comment: ok, changed the example to take this into account

Answer (score 0):

from wikipedia:

> Factorization of large integers is believed to be a computationally
>   very difficult problem, and the security of many modern cryptography
>   systems is based upon its infeasibility.[11]

your best approach is to brute force the prime factors by mean of the Eratosthenes' sieve or pollard-rho algorithm. Because the numbers aren't so big (100000 at max) you could just precompute all the prime factors very quickly on modern hardware.
cheers

Comment: If you're working on just one number, the sieve of Eratosthenes is just an inefficient way of doing trial division. Pollard's rho algorithm is good, but not so useful here -- you'd need to include a fast primality test for it to be worthwhile, and in any case it would be slower than trial division in this range.

Comment: obviously trivial division would be ok. In any case the problem lacks context. If he must compute the prime factors of many integer values it should be better to precompute all the factors for every number (no matter what algorithm he would use). If he just need the prime factors of only one number just try all the divisors.

Comment: For this small range a lookup table might be best, but probably not a naive one from 1 to a million. It would probably be better (more cache-friendly) to make a smaller table, e.g., just the odds using an intrinsic to divide out the factors of 2 in two operations.